# How to get view rate from Youtube Analytics API?

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I have been reading through the API docs for YouTube, but I am having a hard time figuring out how I can calculate the number of views per week of a given video in Python. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The [YouTube Analytics and Reporting APIs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics) does not provide a metric of the kind you need -- views per week (as far as I know).

The [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) doesn't provide the info you need -- views per week -- either, but you may well compute that yourself base on this property:

> [`statistics.viewCount`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#statistics.viewCount) (unsigned long)
> The number of times the video has been viewed.

Thus, you should call the [`Videos.list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) API endpoint, passing on to it the parameters `id=VIDEO_ID` and `part=statistics`, where `VIDEO_ID` is the ID of the video you're interested in.

Arrange your program to read the `viewCount` property weekly, for computing the *views per week* as needed.

---

In the context of Python, if you're using the [Google APIs Client Library for Python](http://github.com/google/google-api-python-client), then your call to the `Videos.list` endpoint would look like:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
youtube = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey = APP_KEY)

response = youtube.videos().list(
    id = VIDEO_ID,
    part = 'statistics',
    fields = 'items(statistics(viewCount))',
    maxResults = 1
).execute()

view_count = response['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount']
```

Note that the code above is simplified quite much since there's no error handling.

Also note that the code above is using the parameter [`fields`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#fields) to obtain from the endpoint *only* the `viewCount` property. (It's always good to ask from the API only the info that is really needed.)

Yet another caveat using this endpoint is the following:

Even if the official doc says that the endpoint's response contains a `viewCount` property of type `unsigned long`, the actual JSON response has the value of that property being of type string:

```json
{
  "items": [
    {
      "statistics": {
        "viewCount": "54508"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Thus, the variable `view_count` above will be of type `str`; using it as an integer would, of course, require a conversion of form `int(view_count)`.